# How MPAndroidChart markerView xAxis show different data in Android?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

About MPAndroidChart Lib , I design custom MakeView to show date and degree , like this :

[image]

I hope makerView show 03/05 , not only 05 , I know xAxis value form :

```
   ArrayList<String> xValue = new ArrayList<>(); //for date(month/day)
   ArrayList<String> label = new ArrayList<>(); //for date(day)
   List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();    //for degree

   //here is data resource from....
   String[] str = data.getTestDate().split("-");
        String thisMonth = str[1];      //Month
        String DayOfMonth = str[2];     //day
        String testDay = thisMonth + "/" + DayOfMonth;  // Month/Day

        if (data.getTemperature() > 0) {
            Entry entry = new Entry(i, (float) data.getTemperature());
            entries.add(entry);             //degree
        }

        label.add(DayOfMonth);   //Day
        xValue.add(testDay);     //Month/Day  

        //now set xAxis is label(only day ex:05)
         xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(label));
```

OK , makerView:

```
       public class LineChartMarkView extends MarkerView{

       private TextView tvDate;
       private TextView tvValue;
       private IAxisValueFormatter xAxisValueFormatter;

       public LineChartMarkView(Context context, IAxisValueFormatter xAxisValueFormatter) {
                    super(context, R.layout.layout_markview);
                    this.xAxisValueFormatter = xAxisValueFormatter;

                    tvDate = findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
                    tvValue = findViewById(R.id.tv_value);
       }

       @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
       @Override
       public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {
             tvDate.setText(xAxisValueFormatter.getFormattedValue(e.getX(), null));
             tvValue.setText("" + e.getY() + "\u2103");
             super.refreshContent(e, highlight);
       }

    }
```

Yes , i  get only day , just like my photo , is any idea let makerView will show 03/05 ?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I find the solution , all I need is pass all data to LineChartMarkView,

for example:

```
  dataBean data = dataList.get((int) e.getX());
  tvDate.setText(data.getDay());
```